# Is it possible to merge a Visual Studio project into a single file?

Tags: visual-studio, text

I just want to have all my code in one file to send around and review.

here is an idea of what I want.

```
****Myclass.cs****
code
code
code
code
code
*****file2.cs*****
code
code
code
```

Comment: No no no. I want a single text file, so I could say paste it into a SO post. Like this look at answer #2 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-data-explorer/2678#2678

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from posting each class underneath each other.

Comment: Add them as two code blocks? You can put second file's name before you paste the second code block.

Comment: I'm talking 50+ files, and that was an example for how I would use it. Manually copying and pasting the content of 50 code files into a single file would take some time and leave room for lots of mistakes.

Comment: Then write a script to do it, of course.

Comment: Install cygwin, add to path, `find path/to/my/project -name '*.cs' | xargs cat`

Comment: @Rafe Kettler, I'll try that.

Comment: @Rafe Kettler, Please make an answer. That worked great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even simpler:

```
type *.cs > oneFile.txt
```

Though this won't put any delimiters between the files. However this:

```
type *.cs >output.txt 2>&1
```

will put the file name before each file's contents.

Comment: +1 for getting me my file names!  Now how do do regex like the `following /^.*\.(inc|cs|vb|cshtml)$/` The example I found was extrememly verbose and complex

Answer (score 0):

Install cygwin, add to path, then run `find path/to/my/project -name '*.cs' | xargs cat` from the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with DOS commands - no need to install cygwin:

```
for %f in (*.cs) do  (
   if exist oneFile.txt del oneFile.txt
   echo %f ---- File: %f ---- >> oneFile.txt
   type %f >> oneFile.txt
)
```

If you have different types of files, you can actually key in their names instead of "*.cs"